# Netty handles messages in only one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I have some problems with netty.

Some years ago I used smartfox server 1.6x, and it's multithreading model led me to handle messages for my connection in different threads. And that feature  forced me to write some thread synchronizing code to let all messages being handled correctly.

Now I use netty, as it is amazing and very useful product for my goals.

So, I implemented some server-based logic. My test was the following

- server add messages to the queue, handles each message and current thread sleeps for 3 seconds
- client spams about 10 messages per second

And I saw that before first messages (first ten) are not handled (about 30 seconds of time generally) the second pack of messages is not handling in parallel thread.

---

**So the main questions are:**

Does netty handle all messages for one connection in only one thread?
If so, should I implement some additional code to do that in different threads, or that single-thread-for-single-connection model works well?

---

Netty config:

```
    _boss = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    _worker = new NioEventLoopGroup(8);

    _bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    _bootstrap.group(_boss, _worker)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .childHandler(new NettyChannelInitializer())
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    _bootstrap.bind(_port).sync();
```

NettyChannelInitializer:

```
private static final ExtentionHandler SharedExtentionHandler = new ExtentionHandler();
private static final EventExecutorGroup ExtentionEventThreadPool = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(20);

public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception 
{
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(ExtentionEventThreadPool, "extention", SharedExtentionHandler);
}
```

Comment: Netty exploits thread reuse, because creating threads is costly. That is one of reasons making it fast

Answer (score 1):

Netty ensures that the events for the same channel are handled in ordered fashion.  i.e. you never have an ordering issue, but you don't take the advantage of parallelism when the number of connection you deal with is just one.  If you are fine with unordered execution, you could simply delegate your tasks to an ordinary `ExecutorService` you can get from JDK.

Comment: Thank you, Trustin, that information is very useful for me.